# Received data was not a string, or was not a recognised encoding. React Native

Tags: facebook, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I have a problem regarding using GET method from to confirm whether a certain url exists or not. Here is the code.

```
export const checkUrlExist = (url, cb) => {
  fetch(url)
    .then((res) => {
      res.status === 200 ? cb(true) : cb(false)
    })
}
```

Although I managed to get the expected result, but every time it finishes the request.

It will always output **Received data was not a string, or was not a recognised encoding**

Not really sure if it is related to the purpose of this GET method since I am fetching Facebook profile image, but the url of profile image will expire after a while and since I am not storing the image in our database so I need to check whether the user has changed their profile image or not.

Cheers
Well

Comment: Console the response it will give you what is returning

Comment: Having the exact same issue.

Comment: what is the url? please be more specific and debug your code.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same warnings as well but I feel like this is just a generic warning of not being able to interpret binary data (your image) as string or using other encoding methods, such as utf-8.

Moreover, I would assume facebook API returns a redirected url for you to download the image? Rather than returning a string url to view the image.